# Liferay Message Bus between two portlets

Tags: java, liferay, portlet, liferay-6, message-bus

I am having problems with the Message Bus, Hope you can help me.

I have 2 portlets

In the portlet 1 a regiostr all the listner  and the destinations

```
<bean id="destination.notification" class="com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.ParallelDestination">
    <property name="name" value="test/notification" />
</bean>

<bean id="messagingConfigurator" class="com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.config.PluginMessagingConfigurator">
    <property name="messageListeners">
        <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.util.List">
            <entry key="test/notification">
                <list value-type="com.liferay.portal.kernel.messaging.MessageListener">
                    <ref bean="messageListener.test_listener" />
                </list>
            </entry>
        </map>
    </property>
    <property name="destinations">
        <list>
            <ref bean="destination.notification"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Everything works fine, when I send a message from Portlet 1 all the listner that are in the same portlet are executed.

But I don't understand how I can  register a Listner on the same message  in portlet 2?

Hope sameone can help me.

Marco

Comment: I think different portlets you mean you are having those Portlets in different plugin projects (i.e. in separate WARs)? in the other portlet you can specify the same `<entry key="test/notification">` and give different listener `<ref bean="messageListener.portlet2_test_listener" />`.

Comment: @RasabihariKumar, yes you are right, I mean two plugins. I tried it , but is not working, And I can't understand how to figure out